# The parameterized query ... which was not supplied

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, ado.net

Im trying to query an UPDATE for my database, and it gives me an error :

> The parameterized query '(@naming nvarchar(7),@role nvarchar(3),@company nvarchar(3),@sal' expects the parameter '@link_company', which was not supplied.

This is my code :

```
<tr>
            <td><input type="text" name="name" value=" <%=dt.Rows[0][1].ToString() %>" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="role" value=" <%=dt.Rows[0][2].ToString() %>" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="company" value=" <%=dt.Rows[0][3].ToString() %>" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="salary_year" value=" <%=dt.Rows[0][4].ToString() %>" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="bonus" value=" <%=dt.Rows[0][5].ToString() %>" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="stock" value=" <%=dt.Rows[0][6].ToString() %>" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="other" value=" <%=dt.Rows[0][7].ToString() %>" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="alut_year" value=" <%=dt.Rows[0][8].ToString() %>" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="alut_monthly" value=" <%=dt.Rows[0][9].ToString() %>" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="net" value=" <%=dt.Rows[0][10].ToString() %>" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="link_name" value=" <%=dt.Rows[0][11].ToString() %>" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="link_company" value=" <%=dt.Rows[0][12].ToString() %>" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="last_year_alut" value=" <%=dt.Rows[0][13].ToString() %>" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="avg_salary" value=" <%=dt.Rows[0][14].ToString() %>" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="last_year_profit" value=" <%=dt.Rows[0][15].ToString() %>" /></td>

        </tr>
```

and this is my code behind :

```
 string name = Request.Form["name"];
        string role = Request.Form["role"];
        string company = Request.Form["company"];
        string salary_year = Request.Form["salary_year"];
        string bonus = Request.Form["bonus"];
        string stock = Request.Form["stock"];
        string other = Request.Form["other"];
        string alut_year = Request.Form["alut_year"];
        string alut_monthly = Request.Form["alut_monthly"];
        string net = Request.Form["net"];
        string link_name = Request.Form["link_name"];
        string link_company = Request.Form["link_comapny"];
        string avg_salary = Request.Form["avg_salary"];
        string last_year_profit = Request.Form["last_year_profit"];
        string last_year_alut = Request.Form["last_year_alut"];


        if (IsPostBack)
        {

            sq.UpdateManager(update,name, role, company, salary_year, bonus, stock, other, alut_year, alut_monthly, net, link_name, link_company,last_year_profit, last_year_alut, avg_salary);
            Response.Redirect("insert.aspx");
        }
```

and this is my "UpdateManager" function :

```
public void UpdateManager(string id, string name, string role, string company, string salary_year, string bonus, string stock, string other, string alut_year, string alut_monthly, string net, string link_name, string link_company, string last_year_profit, string last_year_alut, string avg_salary)
    {
        sql = "Update table_salary SET f_name =@naming , role_manager = @role, COMPANY = @company, SALARY_YEAR =@salary_year ,BONUSING = @bonus,STOCK =@stock ,OTHER = @other, ALUT_YEAR =@alut_year,ALUT_MONTH=@alut_monthly,NET_INCOME=@net,link_name = @link_name, link_company= @link_company,LAST_YEAR_ALUT=@last_year_alut, AVG_SALARY=@avg_salary, LAST_YEAR_PROFIT=@last_year_profit   where id =" + id;
        connection = new SqlConnection(conn);
        connection.Open();

        cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@naming", name);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@role", role);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@company", company);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@salary_year", salary_year);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bonus", bonus);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stock", stock);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@other", other);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@alut_year", alut_year);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@alut_monthly", alut_monthly);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@net", net);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@link_name", link_name);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@link_company", link_company);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@avg_salary", avg_salary);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@last_year_profit", last_year_profit);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@last_year_alut", last_year_alut);

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        connection.Close();
    }
```

When I tried to run this query on my SQL management tool , it runs ok. and NO column is required (any column except of the ID..) allowing null..which is weird..

any thoughts ?

Comment: typo Request.Form["link_comapny"];

Answer (score 0):

typo Request.Form["link_comapny"];